# Bootstrap Datepicker - Show 2 months instead of 1 month range

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

When i use below code.. i can able to view only 1 month calendar.. Is it possible to show 2 months??

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
  <input class="form-control input-lg" id="returnTripDepart" name="start" readonly="true">
  <input class="form-control input-lg" id="returnTripReturn" name="end" readonly="true">
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
    "startDate": today,
    "endDate": maxLimitDate,
    "todayHighlight": true,
    "format": "dd M yyyy",
    "autoclose": true,
    "orientation": "bottom"
});
```